# Splitting array in python many columns

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm use to splitting arrays

```
a = open('filename.txt','r')
b = a.readlines()
a.close()
c = len(b)
d = list(zip(*(e.split() for e in b)))

self.r11 = []
self.r21 = []
self.yr = []
self.mn = []
self.dy = []
self.f = d[0]
self.g = d[1]
self.h = d[2]
self.i = d[3]
self.j = d[4]
for n in range(2, c):
    nn = int(self.f[n])
    if nn > mm:
        self.yr.append(self.f[n])
        self.mn.append(self.g[n])
        self.dy.append(self.h[n])
        self.r11.append(self.i[n])
        self.r12.append(self.j[n])
```

etc...

I now have a csv database that is much bigger at least in terms of the number of columns(144).  Total grid is 144,73.

What is the easiest way of splitting off the data.  I figure you would want to put it into a multidimensional array but what is the easiest way of doing it?  I will be working with both, depending on when I'm working with and at what level I'm working with it, one file at a time and multiple files at a time(aka, multiple 144,73 files).

Comment: Where does the `self` come from? Is that inside a class function? Can you be more precise what exactly you would like to split and what you mean with splitting off data?

Comment: Yeah, the example I took from one of many similiar programs was taken from a class...didn't even think about that at the time when I posted.  I want to take a csv file and split it apart so I can use the data in my own program.  Since I may be combining multiple files with large amount of columns I've just been unsure how best to go about pulling the data off the list and setting up the array.  Thinking more overnight I might have an idea but haven't had a chance to try it out yet, still trying to fully formulate the idea in my head.  I might be trying to make it more complex then I should.